# Wolf 49cc One spark at initial crank then nothing

Tags: scooter, spark

My Wolf 2018 scooter only gives an initial spark when first cranking. Then it cranks and nothing. Turn key off and retry and same thing happens.

I changed the cdi box and spark plug wire too.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Could you please explain how you know there is one spark, then no spark? Are you using a scope? A spark tester?